# Bootstrap modal 'loaded' event on remote fragment

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm currently using Twitter Bootstrap modal component and i have an issue where I use jquery validation plugin on input fields in the content I load remotely using the data-remote attribute.

Because the content is loaded after jquery validation has run across the dom, validation doesn't occur for the newly loaded elements.

I have a solution where I modify bootstrap.js (the modal class), see below.

```
  var Modal = function (element, options) {
    this.options = options
    this.$element = $(element)
      .delegate('[data-dismiss="modal"]', 'click.dismiss.modal', $.proxy(this.hide, this))
    //this.options.remote && this.$element.find('.modal-body').load(this.options.remote)

    this.options.remote && this.$element.find('.modal-body').load(this.options.remote, $.proxy(function () {
        this.$element.trigger('loaded')
    }, this)) //my additions
  }
```

I trigger a 'loaded' event to the call that loads the external html fragment.

I already have this event wired up and i call the validation on the newly loaded elements.

```
$('#myModal').on('loaded', function () {
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(this));
            });
```

My issue is that I had to modify bootstrap.js to achieve this, is there a way I can have this working externally without modifying bootstrap.js? Is there a way to access the modal object on a page and attach the 'loaded' event to it? i'd like to do this in an external script or within a page so i don't need to worry about bootstrap versions.

Comment: Is there an issue with doing the validation in the `shown` event of the modal?

Comment: @mccannf For remote content, the shown triggers before the new elements are loaded.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to both these issues:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5169

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6846

..as of now the Bootstrap developers are digging their heels in and refusing to add a `loaded` event into Bootstrap.

So instead they recommend you avoid using the `data-remote` markup and load the data yourself into the modal:

```
$('#myModal').modal(your_options).find('.modal-body').load('request_url', function () {
  // do cool stuff here all day… no need to change bootstrap
}')
```

Comment: You are great! Thank for this solution! This helped me with this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339958/bootstrap-modal-dialogs-shown-bs-modal-event-doesnt-fire

Comment: Just a quick note so people don't just go with the accepted answer without checking. Bootstrap has had a 'loaded.bs.modal' event for a while now - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals.

Answer (score 36):

Just an update here:

Bootstrap has added a loaded event.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

capture the 'loaded.bs.modal' event on the modal

```
$('#myModal').on('loaded.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do cool stuff here all day… no need to change bootstrap
})
```

Comment: Thanks you prevented me from having no more hair on my head!

Comment: Please remove the ' from the last line. It should be }) not }')

Comment: This event work only when content of the modal is loaded with remote option, if the content is embeded in the html modal not work

Comment: Any idea when this was added? It's not working for me

Comment: This work when we need to call a function after loading script in bootstrap remote modal . Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

The 'loaded.bs.modal' event doesn't work for me, so I have tried the 'shown.bs.modal' event and it's works fine :

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   // do cool stuff here...
});
```

This event is captured after the modal is shown.

I hope this will help someone :)

Comment: the modals first shows, then loads the remote content, so it doesn't work

Comment: This isn't relevant to the question. The question involves ajax loaded content and 'shown' is never triggered as a product of an ajax response.

Comment: Worked for me too. My modal-body is loaded with ajax, then shown. Maybe not relevant to the question, but helpful for some of us :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a rather interesting catch, In my case, on localhost, the event `loaded.bs.modal` was firing **before** the event `shown.bs.modal` since on local host the act of fetching the data from the "`remote`" url(*which was local btw*), was happening instanteneously even before the bootstrap could finish its transition and trigger the `shown.bs.modal` event.

But on a webserver the events were firing in the **perceived order**.

First the `shown.bs.modal` was being triggered and then owing to the pragmatic latency of the remote url, the event `loaded.bs.modal` was being triggered.

**What I wanted is to grab an event whichever happened the last.**

So to solve it I came up with my own implementation as below. YMMV, Now there are a lot of assumptions here, so take the below code as just a POC and with a grain of salt rather than a full fledged code.

```
jQuery('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    if (jQuery(this).find('.resetFlag').length) {
        // Do something ONLY IF "loaded.bs.modal" hasn't yet been triggered
    }
});
jQuery('#myModal').on('loaded.bs.modal', function (e) {

    if (jQuery(this).find('.resetFlag').length) {
        // Do something ONLY IF "shown.bs.modal" hasn't yet been triggered
        } else  {
        // Do something ONLY IF "shown.bs.modal" hasn already been triggered
        }
});
jQuery('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    jQuery('#myModal .modal-content').html('<div class="resetFlag" style="display:none;"></div>');
    showModalLoader();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Boostrap 3.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-events)'s modal events has the `loaded.bs.modal` event.

however in [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events)'s modal events dose not have this event. I would recommend using the `shown.bs.modal` event as it fires after the CSS has been rendered