# Is there a bootstrap modal onloaded (or similar) function when using remote content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Bootstrap has a modal-method with a **remote** option. I want to perform some actions on the content that has been loaded by Jquery/Bootstrap. (e.g., scan for specific classes and replace content on the fly).

Is there an 'onloaded' option in the modal() method?

```
$('#someplaceholder'.modal({
    remote: "data/whatever/123",
    onloaded: function() {
    // perform some substitution,...
        },
});
```

I solve this now by using a setTimeout() function; but this is not an elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap modal 'loaded' event on remote fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959258/bootstrap-modal-loaded-event-on-remote-fragment)

There is no loaded event and it doesn't look like bootstrap is providing a fix for this. You can do the following.

```
$('#someplaceholder').modal().find('.modal-body').load("data/whatever/123", function (data) {
    //do stuff with returned data here
});
```

Comment: Good luck if you have 20 modals :) I am sure the bootstrap guys not have implemented an `onLoaded` event since it would be redundant. You already have the nessecary "infrastructure" in jQuery, and if you need the functionality you can add this by 2 or 3 lines of code. Better than tweak the entire modal initialization.